# Server tag is not well-formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

It says that my server tag is not well-formed.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Fullname"style="width:400px; height:25px; font-family:'Century Gothic'; -webkit-border-radius:5px; border-style:none; margin-left:10px;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Fullname" style="width:400px; height:25px; font-family:'Century Gothic'; -webkit-border-radius:5px; border-style:none; margin-left:10px;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Saw that no space in between the ending double quote for `placeholder` and `style`.

Comment: thanks man. dont know why I didn't notice that

Comment: You are welcome @DawsonKlayGuinang :like:

Comment: @DawsonKlayGuinang is it the right answer? Can you mark it as that?